# How to prove the existence of a fixed point of this mapping?

Tags: convergence-divergence, fixed-point-theorems

Let $X=\{x_i : i\in I\}\subseteq\mathbf{R}^n$, where $I=\{1,\ldots,m\}$. Then for some initialization $\mu^{(t)}$, and $\pi^{(t)}=\{x\in X : \|x-\mu^{(t)}\|\leq r\}$, $r>0$, we want to prove that a mapping $\mu^{(t+1)}=M(\mu^{(t)})$ defined as $$
\mu^{(t+1)}=\textrm{argmin}_{\mu}\sum_{x\in \pi^{(t)}}\|x-\mu\|
$$has a fixed point, i.e. there exist $\mu^*$ such that $\mu^*=M(\mu^*)$. We observe Euclidean norm.

Comment: Why is the minimiser unique?

Comment: It is unique because we observe Euclidean norm, i.e. for other norms the minimiser can be not-unique (for example $\ell_1$ norm).

Comment: If $\pi^{(t)}$ contains two distinct points then any $\mu$ in $[x_1,x_2]$ is a minimiser, regardless of the norm used.